# .htaccess: redirect with not known subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect using mod_rewrite all URI's ending with a known name, but the subfolders are not known. Something like this:

From:

```
example.com/random1/random2/my-text
```

To:

```
example.com/my-text/
```

`random1` and `random2` are not known. I tried `.*/.*/^my-text$` and many variants but I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE:** Existing .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `^` is a start of string anchor, so that is an obvious mistake in your regex, but otherwise it is often useful to see the actual code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect all URLs that end with `my-text` using mod_rewrite in .htaccess, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .+/(my-text)$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

Note that the source URL does not end with a slash, but the destination does (as per your example).

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to a `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK - assuming this should be a permanent redirect?

Note that *external redirects* should generally go before any existing  directives in your .htaccess file that rewrites the request. (So, the above should go immediately after the `RewriteBase` directive in your existing .htaccess file. `RewriteEngine` only needs to appear once.)

Comment: Thank you, it's working. But after many attempts. My original .htaccess was like this
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`
With the rule before the `</IfModule>` , it didn't worked. But now it's working just after `RewriteEngine On`. Why is that?

Comment: Yes, if you have existing directives in .htaccess then the above _redirect_ should come _before_ any other directives. Your existing directives internally rewrite _all requests_ to `index.php` (called a "front controller"). Any attempt to rewrite the request after that simply won't get executed. The order of directives in .htaccess is important.